# go http client transport set DisableCompression is true, then my client cant reuse socket

Tags: http, go, compression, reusability, keepalived

client transport is `http.Transport{DisableKeepAlives: false, DisableCompression: true}`
http server normal, and keepalive is starting.
in this case, cant reuse socket, every request will create new socket.

First. server use `router.Use(gzip.Gzip(gzip.DefaultCompression, gzip.WithDecompressFn(gzip.DefaultDecompressHandle))), and client dont set DisableCompression`
every thing is normal. link can reuse.
After I want close compression, I set `DisableCompression` is True. Then can't reuse link. Delete server gzip, it did not effect.